# Dale - Lever screw on rosette internal door handles

Tags: doors

We have bought 7 pairs x Dale lever handles with screw on rosette covers. I’ve fitted 2 doors with their handles with no problems but now found the remaining 5 screw on covers as supplied are too firmly screwed on to full door handles to undo. You Tube videos show non-screw on where you tap with rubber screwdriver handle but what can I use on screw on so I don’t damage. Thank You - Martin “Oldie” D.I.Y’er.

Comment: Picture of the handles (both installed and uninstalled) showing the screws that are the problem would be of great help. Also, a link to the installation PDF or pictures of the instruction manual are helpful, too. You can simply [edit] your post, then drag the pictures into the text edit box (or click the "sun & mountain" icon above the text entry box) - the site will upload, host & embed the images for you. Then, take the [tour] and browse the [help] while you're waiting to see how to get the most from this site.

Comment: Many Thanks to Freeman and others for looking at my question. I found an article from a Carpenter/Joiner and he used a Boa constrictor strap (see Ebay). I had something similar in the unused diy in my garage and it worked! I wrapped masking tape around the brass rosette as he suggested in case of marking, twisted whilst keeping the pressure and eureka, it worked! Thanks again. Regards Martin

Comment: Glad you go this resolved. Please, post your answer down there in the "Answer" box instead of as a comment. That way you can also click the check-mark so that others will know that this one is resolved - they'll find it more helpful that way. Additionally, you could even include pictures and/or a link to a "boa constrictor strap", as that's not something I've ever heard of.